# How to delete Room entry from EditActivity?

Tags: android, android-room, delete-row

I have an adapter and RecyclerView to display the list of contacts saved locally. When the user clicks on an entry, a new activity is launcher where they can edit it. However, I also want to have a "Delete" button at the very bottom to delete the entry, and then go back to the adapter activity. Using the delete query of Room, or otherwise, how can I delete the entry from the EditContact activity?

In ContactDao, I have the following:

```
// Delete single entry
@Query("DELETE FROM contacts_table WHERE id = :userId")
void deleteByContactId(long userId);
```

ContactRepository:

```
public void delete(Contact contact) {
    new DeleteContactAsyncTask(contactDao).execute(contact);
}
```

```
private static class DeleteContactAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Contact, Void, Void> {

        private ContactDao contactDao;

        private DeleteContactAsyncTask(ContactDao contactDao) {
            this.contactDao = contactDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {
            contactDao.delete(contacts[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Finally, I want in EditContact to delete the entry on click:

```
public void deleteContact(View view) {
    // Delete the entry based on the ID
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi write a query in your dao file

```
//get a contact
@Query("select * FROM contacts_table WHERE id = :userId")
Contact getConatctByContactId(long userId);
```

Once you get the contact id in your edit activity, call ths function to get the contact.

But since your delete function works with id only, you do not need to retrieve to delete from the table

**UPDATE**

declare the dao in the database class

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract ContactDao contactDao();
}
```

And call it using your database instance

```
database.contactPointDao().deleteContact()
```

Comment: Ok so I want to use `deleteByContactId()` to keep things simple. Is it possible to do so by declaring a ContactDao object, passing it the ID from EXTRA_ID, and then calling `deleteByContactId()`?

Comment: @George the query that you have written should work.

Comment: I think so too, but how do I use it? Do I have to call it in my ContactRepository class, similar to how I do for deleteAllContacts()? https://ibb.co/gz3r660

Comment: Yes, delete all contacts should be similar to this

Comment: Thanks @TheBat. The app is now complaining about accessing the DB on the main thread: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` Hence, I need to do it through the repository, as I previously mentioned. I was also confused with all the AsyncTasks and how to use doInBackground(), but I'll look into that also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was extensively trying to debug my code because I forgot to call .execute() at the end of my `DeleteContactByIdAsyncTask(contactDao, id)`;

Below are my final code snippets:

ContactDao:

```
// Delete single entry
    @Query("DELETE FROM contacts_table WHERE id = :userId")
    void deleteByContactId(long userId);
```

ContactRepository:

```
private static class DeleteContactByIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Contact, Void, Void> {

        private ContactDao contactDao;
        private int id;

        private DeleteContactByIdAsyncTask(ContactDao contactDao, int id) {
            this.contactDao = contactDao;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {
            contactDao.deleteByContactId(id);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ContactViewModel:

```
public void deleteContactById(int id) {
        contactRepository.deleteContactById(id);
    }
```

And, in the ViewContact activity, upon returning the result:

```
if (requestCode == EDIT_CONTACT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && isDeleted) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            contactViewModel.deleteContactById(id);
            onBackPressed();

        }
```

And that's it. Entry is deleted, and upon returning to the activity with the RecyclerView, the entries are automatically updated.